# Access PowerShell parameters inside Python

Tags: python, powershell, parameters

I have a set of parameters inside my .ps1 (PowerShell) script:

```bsh
$password = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto( $bytes )
$DBUser = "myDBuser"
$DBPass = $password
$DBTNS = "myTNSname"
type $args[0] | sqlplus -s $DBUser/$DBPass@$DBTNS
```

My security setting for my machine are "RemoteSigned". I test this using a test sql to a DB and it works. So i know the parameters values are passed correctly AND that the .PS1 script runs.

However, I tried doing that inside a Python script and it gives me a strange error:

```
python Test.py
C:\PowerShell\run_sqlplus.ps1 : File C:\PowerShell\run_sqlplus.ps1 cannot be
loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more information,
see about_Execution_Policies at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1
+ C:\PowerShell\run_sqlplus.ps1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
```

Just for the heck of it, I even tried making it Unrestricted but it still didn't work; because if that was the issue, the test.sql should have failed too but it didn't.
Any pointers/suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried `powershell.exe -executionpolicy unrestricted -command C:\PowerShell\run_sqlplus.ps1` ? What's the user python is running under?

Comment: Please show the output of `Get-ExecutionPolicy -List`.

Comment: Could potentially be caused by different user as @PedroLobito mentions. Could also be caused by `64bit`/`32bit` as the different shells have separate policies - check the policy in your `Windows PowerShell (x86)` console.